# What is this white five-petal nice-smelling flower on a bush? (vine?)

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs, vines

What is this white five-petal nice-smelling flower on a bush? (vine? It seems to be supported by some tree but I'm not sure it wasn't the tree itself. It also seemed to me when I was taking the picture that the leaves in the picture were the flower's leaves.)

Here is its picture:

[image]

I'd also like to know how to grow it. I put a branch in a vase with water, hoping it will sprout roots. But that never happened. But that is a separate question. My question now is what the plant is so I can google how to grow it.

Comment: Where in the world did you find it?  What does it smell like?  Are those the leaves of the plant in the picture?  Was it climbing something or did it stand on its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone suggested that it is called "Jasminum azoricum" and from an image search it looks just like it. So [if it looks like a Jasmine and smells like a Jasmine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test)...

In case someone has reason to say otherwise, I'd be happy to be notified. (I'm not an expert so it might *look* the same to me but clearly be something else to an expert.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That is my guess as well.  If this is it, it should smell lemon-y, have opposing groups of 3 leaves, and it should be a vine that climbs by sending out twinning stems. You can also propagate them through cuttings or layerings, which is the only thing from OP that didn't match.  But that could just have been a failed cutting. http://www.flowersofindia.net/catalog/slides/Azores%20Jasmine.html